# What Drupal-specific solution resources are there on the web? Does DSE have/need this?

Tags: discussion

I just recently discovered [Drupal Bin](http://drupalbin.com/). Personally, I can't find anything on the site with a search, and yet I know I will find it useful later when I graduate from Views/CCK/Panels stage of Drupal development.

What other Drupal specific web resources are people using besides this [pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin)? Has anyone found a [cookbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookbook#Usage_outside_the_world_of_food) of useful solutions? I am particularly interested to find anything that can offer details for [interaction design patterns.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_design_pattern#Elements_of_an_interaction_design_pattern)

I suspect Drupal development, with its complexity of solutions using core, modules, and custom code, could benefit by more sites like drupalbin and fewer sites with only forum resources--structured contribution.

Does stack have its own pastebin? Should drupal.SE have a structured database of solutions--a place to promote a great answer?